# trigger signal of QToolButton autorepeat the action

Tags: python, qt4.7

Hi in my application I have several gui developped with QT4.7, in some of them I use QToolButton for interaction, everything work nicely, except that when I click over each of the QToolButton, the slot linked to  his triggered signal is called twice,
I  have no more Ideas about a olution to that, can you help me please, thanks in advance

Comment: If you have found a solution to your own question, you should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I solved, when clicked the QtoolButton send two different triggered signal, then my slot  ran twice, it was enough  to add decorator before the definition of the slot
    @pyqtSignature("")